# French words with memoir demo chapterstyle

Tags: memoir, babel, french

I am looking for an easy solution to have the chapter numbers written in French words while using the `\chapterstyle{demo}` with the `memoir` class. If I use `\chapterstyle{default}`, the word "chapter" is translate into the word "chapitre", which is perfect, but the number (written in letters) is not translated.

Here is a MWE in which the `\chapterstyle` is the default one. As you see, the word "chapter" is translated as it should by `babel`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\author{J.P. Le Cavalier}
\title{This is an MWE}
\date{\today}

%\chapterstyle{demo}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier chapitre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the following MWE, I just uncommented the line to set the chapter style to `demo`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\author{J.P. Le Cavalier}
\title{This is an MWE}
\date{\today}

\chapterstyle{demo}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier chapitre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have "One" translated into "Un" (which is the French word for "one").

Thanks!

Comment: Consider `\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}`. You may want to check out [this blog](https://texblog.org/2017/04/11/chapter-numbers-as-words-in-latex/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You may want to know how to make a Minimum Working Example. Consider `\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}`. You may also want to check out [this blog](https://texblog.org/2017/04/11/chapter-numbers-as-words-in-latex/)

Comment: You could try `\usepackage{fmtcount}` and `\let\numtoName\Numberstringnum`. It will probably break something, but we do love breaking TeX documents. `:)`

Comment: Here is a question where [MWE gets explained](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I just edited my question with an MWE. Could someone correct this example's code so that it will work fine? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fmtcount`, which is language-aware, to redefine `\printchapternum`. Note the language options of `babel` should be be loaded with the document class since version 3.10.

```
\documentclass[french]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}

\author{J.P. Le Cavalier}
\title{This is an MWE}
\date{\today}

\chapterstyle{demo}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\Numberstring{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Premier chapitre}
\chapter{Second chapitre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This work fine! However, I get this warning : `Package fmtcount Warning: \ordinal already defined use \FCordinal instead.` What does it means?

Comment: It's only a warning: `\ordinal is defined by both `fmtcount` and `memoir`, and suggests to use `\FCordinal` if you want the `fmtcount` version. If you don't use this command, you may safely ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

For the first three chapter

```
\chapterstyle{demo}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\printchapternum{%
    \chapnumfont\ifcase\c@chapter\or Un\or Deux\or Trois\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks @Herbert, I guess this could do the job, but I'm sure there's a way to do it without hardcoding. I hate hardcoding :)